# Submenu doesn't overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

The problem is that when i hover **on the area** where the more link is, the menu appears and it should appear only if i have hovered over the More link, **not on the area**. I tried with `overflow:hidden` on the sub-menu `.ktmsg ul li ul {` but doesn't work. 
I have the below code

HTML

```
<div class="ktmsg">
    <li><a id="a0" href="#"> 0 </a></li>
    <ul>
        <li class="a1"><a href="#"> 1 </a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">More</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="a4"><a href="#"> 4 </a></li>
                <li class="a5"><a href="#"> 5 </a></li>
                <li class="a6"><a href="#"> 6 </a></li>
            </ul>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ktmsg {
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0px;
height: 18px;
border-top-right-radius: 8px;
border-top-left-radius: 8px;
width: 930px;
padding: 0px;
text-align: left;
height: 20px;
position: relative;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 15px;
background-color: red;
}

.ktmsg a{
text-align: center;
padding: 13px 4px;
white-space: nowrap;
float: left;
text-decoration: none;
background:red;
color: #FFF;
min-width: 150px;
transition: all 0.4s;
}

.ktmsg ul{
list-style: none outside none;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
padding-left:0px;
}

.ktmsg li {
float:left;
position:relative;
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px 10px;
background-image: none;
}

.ktmsg li a, .ktmenu li a:active, .ktmenu li a:visited {
margin:0px;
color: #FFF;
border: 0px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
}

.ktmsg ul li a:hover {
color: blue;
text-decoration: none;
}

.ktmsg a, .ktmsg a:active, .ktmsg a:visited {
color: #FFF;
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.ktmsg ul li ul {
overflow:hidden;
padding:0;
background:red;
opacity:0;
height:auto; 
width:auto;
margin-top:25px;
position:absolute;
transition-property: opacity;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px;
border-radius: 6px;
transition-duration: 1s;
transition-timing-function: linear;
transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.ktmsg ul li:hover ul{
overflow:visible;
display:block;
background:red;
height:auto; 
width:auto;
margin-top:25px;
opacity: 1;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px;
border-radius: 6px;
}

.ktmsg ul li ul li{
background:red;
padding: 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
}
```

[Fiddle-DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t8FBa/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `min-width` of `.ktmsg a` is set to `150px`. I suggest you to move it to `.ktmsg li` and it should solve problem you are mentioned.

As well you have to change `.ktmsg ul a:hover + ul` this is selector what should be instead to `.ktmsg ul li:hover ul`. And as well `.ktmsg a` shouldn't have `float: left` and paddings.

To `ul` doesn't disappear you have to add one other selector:

```
.ktmsg ul a + ul:hover, 
.ktmsg ul a:hover + ul {
    overflow:visible;
    display:block;
    opacity: 1;
    /* rest of style */
}
```

Comment: Same thing, when i hover in the area it's showing the menu when it should not. It should show it only when i hover on the menu link.

Comment: `.ktmsg ul a:hover + ul` this is selector what should be instead to `.ktmsg ul li:hover ul`. And as well `.ktmsg a` shouldn't have `float: left` and paddings.

Comment: A new problem appeared, when i hover on the menu it doesn't stay hovered. http://jsfiddle.net/t8FBa/5/

Answer (score 0):

I think it is working as you want it to, it's just that you have a min-width of 150px applied to your a links which is making the more link wider than you think it is.

Comment: It's not related to the min-width. It's related to the fact that the menu appears when i hover around it, for example go ahead and hover 30px down where the More link is like i attached in the screen-shoot. Just go with you mouse exactly where i went from the first move.

Comment: OH! Now I see what the problem is ... sorry I didn't quite understand what you were saying. Ok, to me it looks like it's because you're not removing the sub menu but simply changing the opacity ... so it's still there in the space, and because it's a child of the a link it's acting as the link. In order to stop that happening you need to remove it completely somehow (classic suckerfish would use something like -999em on left position).

Answer (score 0):

```
.ktmsg ul li ul {
 overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: Tried http://jsfiddle.net/t8FBa/3/, same problem like in the screen shoot http://postimg.org/image/7qf8s83g5/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `min-width: 150px;` from style

Comment: Tried removing, still same thing, i believe that is not because of min width.

Comment: I tired removing min-width: 150px; in your created "Fiddle-DEMO" and it is working fine.
Using min-width: 150px;, you are setting with of anchor to 150px. So that cannot be achieved to just hover over the text. Because text is inside anchor tag and anchor with is 150px;. So whenever you hover on that 150px submenu will be displayed.

Please correct if i am wrong.